# Why would seed method work properly, but queries not work?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I'm using EF to manage my database and I've successfully set up the database, ran my migration, updated the database, and checked in MSSQL Studio to confirm that the records are there.

However, when I try and run a query against the DB, the debug window prints

> Exception thrown: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in System.Data.dll

until it seems like the call eventually times out nothing gets returned.

Here is my query.

```
public async Task<Feature> GetFeatureById(int id){
   try {return await _dbcontext.Features.FirstAsync(m => m.Id == id); }
   catch (Exception e) {return null;}
}
```

I've also tried this variation:

```
return await (await _dbcontext.Features.AnyAsync(m => m.Id == id) ?
        _dbcontext.Features.FirstAsync(m => m.Id == id) :
        Task.Run(() => new Feature()));
```

And this variation:

```
_dbcontext.Features.SqlQuery(
    String.Format("SELECT * FROM [Features] WHERE {0} = Id", id))
    .FirstAsync();
```

---

**Edit:**
This is the message from the debug console when i print out the exception message:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.

Which adds to my confusion, since, like I said, the project connects to the DB just fine when I run "Update-Database -StartupProject [projectName]"

**Edit:**
This is my connection string in app.config

```
<add name="Context" connectionString="Data Source=localhost\mssqlserver2008;Initial Catalog=HA_Madmin;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

But when I print out

```
_dbcontext.Database.Connection.ConnectionString
```

I see the following:

```
Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Context;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True
```

Comment: What was the error message of the exception?

Comment: What's the InnerException?

Comment: Can you change that to `catch (Exception e) {return e.Message + e.stackTrace;}`

Comment: @Hackerman Not the stack trace, the e.InnerException.Message will be more useful

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto `e.ToString` would actually provide out all of the relevant information, unlike either of those two options.

Comment: Can you verify that the connection string is set correctly by setting a break point near where the error happens and digging around using a watch?  If you have multiple projects sometimes the connection string doesn't propagate through them the way you expect. It will probably be at `_dbContext.Database.Connection.ConnectionString`

Comment: Anything guys...What I mean it's that we need more info based on the exception!...he can set a breakpoint too and inspect the exception, he can install something like glimpse, whatever xD

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem was there because my application was running in an app pool with a different identity than what my database's connection was set to.